# Adjust Kendo DatePicker Value after other DatePicker

Tags: javascript, c#, kendo-ui, datepicker

I have two Kendo DatePickers to select the start date and the end date. When the page is loaded they both show today's date. When the start date is selected I wrote a script that is limiting the user to chose a date that is after the start date. However would like the end date in the DatePicker value to update to the start date previously selected. Any help would be amazing.

Here is my code:

```
  <div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.StartDate, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10 k-content">
      @(Html.Kendo().DatePicker()
        .Name("StartDate")
        .Max(new DateTime(2020, 12, 31))
        .Value(DateTime.Today.AddDays(1))
        .Events(e => e.Change("startChange"))
        .Culture(ViewBag.Culture)
        .HtmlAttributes(new { @data_val = "false" })
      )
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.EndDate, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10 k-content">
      @(Html.Kendo().DatePicker()
        .Name("EndDate")
        .Min(DateTime.Today)
        .Max(new DateTime(2020, 12, 31))
        .Value(DateTime.Today.AddDays(1))
        .Events(e => e.Change("endChange"))
        .Culture(ViewBag.Culture)
        .HtmlAttributes(new { @data_val = "false" })
      )
    </div>
  </div>
```

And this is the script:

```
function startChange() {
        var endPicker = $("#EndDate").data("kendoDatePicker"),
            startDate = this.value();

        if (startDate) {
            startDate = new Date(startDate);
            startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate());
            endPicker.min(startDate);

        }
    }

    function endChange() {
        var startPicker = $("#StartDate").data("kendoDatePicker"),
            endDate = this.value();

        if (endDate) {
            endDate = new Date(endDate);
            endDate.setDate(endDate.getDate());
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem is not relevant to others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found the answer, that's silly.

```
function startChange() {
        var endPicker = $("#EndDate").data("kendoDatePicker"),
            startDate = this.value();

        if (startDate) {
            startDate = new Date(startDate);
            startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate());
            endPicker.min(startDate);
            endPicker.value(startDate);//added this line

        }
    }
```